Appropriate test for RNA binding data
I have the data on RNA binding by a protein. The dependent variable is the fraction of bound RNA, and the independent variable is protein concentration.  I have such data for one reference RNA and 8 modified variants, all in 3 replicates. I want to compare the binding of different RNA variants to the reference RNA. Value (dependent variable) is not normal since it increases with the increase of protein concentration .Here is a sample of my data (not tidy): 
Protein concentration and measurements for reference RNA (AniS-3') and one modified variant (AniS-loop),  each in 3 replicates.
I have already tried Kruskal-Wallis test followed by Dunn's test, but this detected statistically important differences between the extreme variants (not shown in the screenshot), when there is almost no binding observed.
I wonder if there is some other statistical test that could be more appropriate and sensitive for my data. I would be very grateful for any help!

I think you should state your research question so we can help you better. DO you want to test whether the fraction of bound RNA is explained by something while accounting for the protein concentration ?

Of course, the choice of an analysis must depend on exactly what you are asking.
I asked ChatGPT to OCR your screenshot into values (included at the bottom of my answer). Then I pasted those values into GraphPad Prism to graph. Below is a graph of the raw data. That is always the first step.

These seem like standard concentration-response curves so I fit them to the standard (fixed Hill slope of 1.0) equation. Here is the graph with the fit curves and the best-fit values of the EC50s.

Finally, here are the full nonlinear regression results. But of course these must be interpreted in the context of your experiment.

If these results address your scientific questions, the next step could be to run statistical tests to see if which EC50s differ and maybe which maximum plateau values differ. I suspect this will be WAY more useful than testing individual responses at various doses.
---raw data as OCRed from the screenshot ---
roQ concentration [nM]  AniS-3'_1   AniS-3'_2   AniS-3'_3   AniS-loop_1 AniS-loop_2 AniS-loop_3
0.04882812  0.01776087  0.04861755  0.02439904  0.07290182  0.09999967  0.09286699
0.09765625  0.03758764  0.0455792   0.02775532  0.09277448  0.1039936   0.1548823
0.1953125   0.03359688  0.04898268  0.03887581  0.1002592   0.1723551   0.2412934
0.390625    0.05713899  0.06464233  0.05348803  0.1812604   0.3873054   0.2569409
0.78125 0.0946567   0.0819355   0.09399647  0.2786563   0.3939978   0.4579554
1.5625  0.1770568   0.194344    0.2088279   0.41667 0.3277436   0.4917732
3.125   0.3272468   0.2804658   0.33208 0.4157453   0.4662842   0.5113097
6.25    0.519739    0.4398787   0.561013    0.4488154   0.4965478   0.5040418
12.5    0.741286    0.4915291   0.7346761   0.4896377   0.530023    0.5225505
25  0.8210546   0.6019769   0.8401988   0.4950767   0.5514046   0.558319
50  0.8925729   0.7391696   0.8864928   0.5001281   0.5444464   0.5570529

Thank you, I will try it out!
